# How to remove an Accuride drawer rail on a Diebold fire-safe filing cabinet?

Tags: removal, drawers

The filing cabinet has two Accuride slides on each side of the double wide drawers:

[image: Accuride drawer slide]

Trying to figure out how to remove the drawers for moving purposes.  Don't have a fork lift on delivery end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the rails disconnected from the drawer by sticking a flat head screw driver between the two,  and popping it off the rivets.

Answer (score 2):

We believe this is a 3620, a pocket and bayonet slide. For those type of drawer slides you have to move the drawer away from the locking tab, then lift the bayonet out of the cabinet pocket.  Below is an image so you have a visual reference.

[image: pocket and bayonet]

Comment: You [shouldn't put your email in an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266091/can-email-addresses-or-phone-numbers-be-exchanged-over-stack-exchange) (or question).  It triggers spam alerts as well. ... You can put your email in your profile.